# Match by minimum Euclidean distance in R

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have the following dataset:

```
X <- data.frame(PERMNO = c(10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003),
                Date = c("Nov 2021","Nov 2021","Nov 2021","Dec 2021","Dec 2021","Dec 2021"),
                     ME = c(100,95,110,110,115,108),
                     IVOL = c(1,1.1,0.8,0.7,1,2.1),
                     C = c(NA, 2, 3,NA, 4, 1.5))
```

For firm 10001, the C is missing. I want to fill C, each month, by matching C from other firms by using the firm with non-missing C that minimizes the euclidean distance of the ranked ME and the ranked IVOL with the missing firm:

[image]

X in my application has more PERMNOs and a longer time frame, and multiple firms may have C missing. My question is how to code this efficiently in R.

Taking the ranks is straight forward by using rank() and the Euclidean distance can be calculated using outer() if I am correct. However, I struggle with making the pairs of firm i and j and then selecting the minimum distance and subsequently match C from firm j to the missing C for firm i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.table` solution using `colMins` from the `Rfast` package.

```
library(data.table)

X <- data.frame(PERMNO = c(10001,10002,10003,10001,10002,10003),
                Date = c("Nov 2021","Nov 2021","Nov 2021","Dec 2021","Dec 2021","Dec 2021"),
                ME = c(100,95,110,110,115,108),
                IVOL = c(1,1.1,0.8,0.7,1,2.1),
                C = c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 4, 1.5))

fFillNA <- function(C, ME, IVOL) {
  idxNA <- which(is.na(C))
  C[idxNA] <- C[-idxNA][Rfast::colMins(outer(ME[-idxNA], ME[idxNA], "-")^2 + outer(IVOL[-idxNA], IVOL[idxNA], "-")^2)]
  C
}

setDT(X)[, C := if(anyNA(C)) fFillNA(C, ME, IVOL), by = "Date"]
X
#>    PERMNO     Date  ME IVOL   C
#> 1:  10001 Nov 2021 100  1.0 2.0
#> 2:  10002 Nov 2021  95  1.1 2.0
#> 3:  10003 Nov 2021 110  0.8 3.0
#> 4:  10001 Dec 2021 110  0.7 1.5
#> 5:  10002 Dec 2021 115  1.0 4.0
#> 6:  10003 Dec 2021 108  2.1 1.5
```

No need to take the square root to get the index of the minimum distance. Also, notice that because of relative size, `ME` impacts the distance calculation much more than `IVOL`, at least for the example dataset. Maybe consider normalizing `ME` and `IVOL` in the distance calculation.

Comment: Thank you Jblood94, this seems to do the job and also in my dataframe with 3.5m rows. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```r
library(tidyverse)

X <- data.frame(
  PERMNO = c(10001, 10002, 10003, 10001, 10002, 10003),
  Date = c("Nov 2021", "Nov 2021", "Nov 2021", "Dec 2021", "Dec 2021", "Dec 2021"),
  ME = c(100, 95, 110, 110, 115, 108),
  IVOL = c(1, 1.1, 0.8, 0.7, 1, 2.1),
  C = c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 4, 1.5)
) %>% as_tibble()
X
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   PERMNO Date        ME  IVOL     C
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  10001 Nov 2021   100   1    NA  
#> 2  10002 Nov 2021    95   1.1   2  
#> 3  10003 Nov 2021   110   0.8   3  
#> 4  10001 Dec 2021   110   0.7  NA  
#> 5  10002 Dec 2021   115   1     4  
#> 6  10003 Dec 2021   108   2.1   1.5

imputations <-
  X %>%
  rename_all(~ paste0(.x, ".1")) %>%
  expand_grid(X %>% rename_all(~ paste0(., ".2"))) %>%
  mutate(
    dist = sqrt((rank(ME.1) - rank(ME.2))**2 + (rank(IVOL.1) - rank(IVOL.2))**2)
  ) %>%
  group_by(PERMNO.1) %>%
  filter(PERMNO.1 != PERMNO.2) %>%
  arrange(dist) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  transmute(
    PERMNO = PERMNO.1,
    imputed.C = case_when(
      !is.na(C.1) ~ C.1,
      !is.na(C.2) ~ C.2
    )
  )
imputations
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   PERMNO imputed.C
#>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  10001         3
#> 2  10002         2
#> 3  10003         3

X %>%
  left_join(imputations) %>%
  mutate(C = ifelse(is.na(C), imputed.C, C)) %>%
  select(-imputed.C)
#> Joining, by = "PERMNO"
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   PERMNO Date        ME  IVOL     C
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  10001 Nov 2021   100   1     3  
#> 2  10002 Nov 2021    95   1.1   2  
#> 3  10003 Nov 2021   110   0.8   3  
#> 4  10001 Dec 2021   110   0.7   3  
#> 5  10002 Dec 2021   115   1     4  
#> 6  10003 Dec 2021   108   2.1   1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Danloo! This works as well. The answer above however is much faster for large datasets, but this also does the job!